# Remove character only during search?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which is like an FAQ with lots of Q&A. On the first worksheet there is a search function. You enter the word(s) you want to search for and press enter. The function then looks for these word(s) in the entire workbook. To be able to do a proper search I have to remove all full stop, comma, exclamation and question marks.

I use `Replace` to do this, but didn't really think of the consequences. The characters are remove permanently from the text which makes it a little hard to read and ugly to look at.

So my question is, how can I remove these characters only during the search? Do I have to copy each text to a new cell and do the search there, or is there another way?

This is the part of the function where I remove the characters and to the final search.

```
Function FindWords(cellToSearch As Range, nOfWords As Integer, myWords As String) As Long

Dim counter As Long
Dim word, element
Dim arr, wordsArr

cellToSearch = Replace(cellToSearch, Chr(33), "")
cellToSearch = Replace(cellToSearch, Chr(44), "")
cellToSearch = Replace(cellToSearch, Chr(46), "")
cellToSearch = Replace(cellToSearch, Chr(63), "")

wordsArr = Split(myWords)
arr = Split(cellToSearch)

If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
    For Each word In wordsArr
        For Each element In arr
            If LCase(word) = LCase(element) Then counter = counter + 1
        Next
    Next
Else
    ' cell to search is empty
    counter = 0
End If

If counter = nOfWords Then
    FindWords = 1
Else
    FindWords = 0
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use another variable:

```
Function FindWords(cellToSearch As Range, nOfWords As Integer, myWords As String) As Long

Dim counter As Long
Dim word, element
Dim arr, wordsArr
Dim sFindWord as String
sFindWord = cellToSearch.Value
sFindWord = Replace(sFindWord , Chr(33), "")
sFindWord = Replace(sFindWord , Chr(44), "")
sFindWord = Replace(sFindWord , Chr(46), "")
sFindWord = Replace(sFindWord , Chr(63), "")

wordsArr = Split(myWords)
arr = Split(sFindWord)

If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
    For Each word In wordsArr
        For Each element In arr
            If LCase(word) = LCase(element) Then counter = counter + 1
        Next
    Next
Else
    ' cell to search is empty
    counter = 0
End If

If counter = nOfWords Then
    FindWords = 1
Else
    FindWords = 0
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Wow, I'm really having a monday...Thank you for that quick and easy answer! :D